# QFile seek() vs. FILE* seekg()

Tags: c++, qt, file

I am replacing some `FILE*` data members to `QFile`, and I realized that `FILE*::seek()` moves the cursor relative to the current position when used with `ios_base::cur` flag. `QFile::seek()` sets the cursor always relative to the file start. Is there a way to use `QFile`'s `seek()` the way it works for `FILE*`? (Other than implementing an own QFile class and overriding the seek functionality.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeking forward is easy:

```
file.skip(offset);
```

Seeking backward slightly less so:

```
file.seek(file.pos() - offset);
```